# Inconsistent Tkinter behavior at runtime after code changes

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Note: I am not a programmer by trade or education, so bear with me. Take the following simple application:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class app(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button1= tk.Button(self, text='1')
        self.button1.pack(side='top')

        self.quit_button= tk.Button(self, text='quit', command=self.quit_button.destroy())
        self.quit_button.pack(side='bottom')

application = app(root)
application.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I am told destroy() isn't an method of quit_button. If I change it to:

```
self.quit_button= tk.Button(self, text='quit', command=self.dest)
```

and I add the method:

```
def dest(self):
    self.quit_button.destroy()
```

then it works - I assume this has something to do with the button being unable to reference itself while it's being created (please correct/enlighten me on this if you can since I don't fully understand this behavior).

However, what I'm really asking about is that *the first time* the program is run *after* I get this error, I get one window with both buttons, and X extra windows with *only* button1 (packed appropriately) where X is the number of times I incurred the error. Obviously I can just "not do that" but it would be extremely educative for me to understand how tkinter could be behaving this way. Is anyone here familiar enough with OOP to help? I create the root window before anything else, so there should be only one in any case.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly give you  the error that "destroy" isn't a method. There are several other errors before you ever get to that line of code. You are correct, though, that it has to do with referencing the variable before it has been created.

Comment: The code was never intended to be ran after I converted my variable names to ones that were less confusing for readers, but I've corrected the typos such that it displays the exact behavior if you really really want to run it yourself. It's nothing special.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you've described. The closest thing I can achieve is one window with multiple buttons in it (by calling `app(root)` repeatedly). Please explain in detail what you're doing to get multiple windows.

Comment: Essentially, run the first block of code, receive error. No window is created. Next make the substitution in the second block of code, and add the method in the third block of code to the app class. Now I run it, and get multiple widows, only once. Closing the windows and running the code again gives the proper single window with 3 buttons. Only upon repeating the error, correcting the code, and running the corrected code, do i get multiple windows. I know it's not terribly important but I find it interesting that tkinter manages to make 1 window with 1 button when this shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of problems in your code. All in the line:

```
self.quit_button= tk.Button(self, text='quit', command=self.quit_button.destroy())
```

The first is you're trying to reference `self.quit_button` at the same time you're creating it. The second, somewhat related issue, is the `command=self.quit_button.destroy()` part actually tries to *call* one of this non-existent `Button`'s methods rather than just supplying a reference to it (because of the `()`s following its name).

Here's a version with those problems fixed:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class app(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button1= tk.Button(self, text='1')
        self.button1.pack(side='top')

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='quit')
        self.quit_button.config(command=self.quit_button.destroy)  # set function to execute
        self.quit_button.pack(side='bottom')

application = app(root)
application.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you - this explains the proper way to do what I was attempting.

Comment: My main question was not what was wrong with the code but rather how is it that tkinter manages to create multiple windows missing different widgets if the environment has been conditioned properly. I do appreciate your help

Comment: If you run the the code in your question twice, I don't know of any way for it to function differently the second time—in fact, it sounds impossible.

Comment: I know, it's very unusual which is why I asked the question.

Comment: There must be an explanation. Please describe exactly _how_ you're running the code twice.

Comment: Literally the following: I run the code as given and receive an error. I make the mentioned changes and run the code again. Multiple windows (unusual behavior). I run the exact same code again with no changes at all. One window as expected.

Perhaps I should mention I'm running it in Spyder by clicking "run" (green arrow etc.) and that it's all in the same console.